# yii2- how to get drop down selected value from view to controller

Tags: yii2, dropdown, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on `yii2`. In my view, I have a button which will perform downloading of `pdf` file. Also, I have drop downs and I want to pass the selected drop-down `value` from my view to the controller. The drop-down in my `index` view is.

```
[
            'label' => 'Sub Division Name',
            'value' => function ($d) {
                if(is_object($d->subdiv))
                return $d->subdiv->name;
             return ' - ';
            },
            'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'sub_div', \common\models\SurveyHescoSubdivision::toArrayList(), ['prompt' => "Sub-Div", 'class' => 'form-control']),

        ],
```

The `HTML` generated is

```
<select id="meterssearch-sub_div" class="form-control" name="MetersSearch[sub_div]">
<option value="">Sub-Div</option>
<option value="37111" selected="">37111 - HYD SADDAR</option>
<option value="37112">37112 - GARI KHATA</option>
<option value="37113">37113 - SARFARAZ COLONY</option>
<option value="37115">37115 - LIAQAT COLONY</option>
<option value="37141">37141 - TANDO ALLAH YAR-I</option>
<option value="37142">37142 - TANDO ALLAH YAR-II</option>
<option value="37143">37143 - TANDO JAM</option>
<option value="37144">37144 - CHAMBER</option>
<option value="37151">37151 - HALI ROAD</option>
<option value="37152">37152 - RIZVI HOSPITAL</option>
<option value="37153">37153 - ALLAMA IQBAL</option>
<option value="37154">37154 - SH:UMAID ALI KHAN</option>
<option value="37155">37155 - MIRAN M.SHAH</option>
<option value="37181">37181 - QASIMABAD</option>
<option value="37182">37182 - CITIZEN COLONY</option>
<option value="37183">37183 - HIRABAD</option>
<option value="37221">37221 - KOTRI</option>
<option value="37222">37222 - JAMSHORO</option>
<option value="37223">37223 - SHAHBAZ</option>
<option value="37225">37225 - NOORIABAD</option>
<option value="37226">37226 - SEHWAN SHARIF</option>
<option value="37241">37241 - PARETABAD</option>
<option value="37242">37242 - PHULELI</option>
<option value="37243">37243 - ILYASABAD</option>
<option value="37244">37244 - MEMON HOSPITAL</option>
<option value="37251">37251 - T.MUHAMMAD KHAN-I</option>
<option value="37252">37252 - T.MUHAMMAD KHAN-II</option>
<option value="37253">37253 - MATLI</option>
<option value="37254">37254 - BULRISHAH KARIM</option>
<option value="37271">37271 - THATTA</option>
<option value="37272">37272 - SUJAWAL</option>
<option value="37273">37273 - MAKLI</option>
<option value="37281">37281 - BADIN</option>
<option value="37282">37282 - TALHAR</option>
<option value="37283">37283 - GOLARCHI</option>
<option value="37311">37311 - NAWAB SHAH-I</option>
<option value="37312">37312 - NAWAB SHAH-II</option>
<option value="37313">37313 - SOCIETY</option>
<option value="37314">37314 - DAUR</option>
<option value="37315">37315 - SAKRAND</option>
<option value="37316">37316 - SAEEDABAD</option>
<option value="37318">37318 - QAZI AHMED</option> 
<option value="37319">37319 - DAULAT PUR</option>
<option value="37331">37331 - TANDO ADAM-I</option>
<option value="37332">37332 - TANDO ADAM-II</option>
<option value="37333">37333 - ODERO LAL</option>
<option value="37334">37334 - MATIARI</option>
<option value="37335">37335 - HALA</option>
<option value="37336">37336 - BHIT SHAH</option>
<option value="37341">37341 - SANGHAR</option>
<option value="37342">37342 - JHOLE</option>
<option value="37343">37343 - SHAHDAD PUR-I</option>
<option value="37344">37344 - SHAHDAD PUR-II</option>
<option value="37345">37345 - KHIPRO</option>
<option value="37346">37346 - SHAHPUR CHAKAR</option>
<option value="37347">37347 - SINDHRI</option>
<option value="37411">37411 - MIPURKHAS CITY</option>
<option value="37412">37412 - SATELLITE TOWN</option>
<option value="37413">37413 - HIRABAD MPK</option>
<option value="37414">37414 - MIRWAH</option>
<option value="37421">37421 - DIGRI</option>
<option value="37422">37422 - JHUDO</option>
<option value="37423">37423 - NAUKOT</option>
<option value="37424">37424 - MITHI</option>
<option value="37431">37431 - UMERKOT</option>
<option value="37432">37432 - PITHORO</option>
<option value="37433">37433 - SAMARO</option>
<option value="37434">37434 - KUNRI</option>
</select>
```

**Update 1**

My `index` view code is

**Two buttons**

```
<p>
    <?= Html::a('<i></i> Create Meters', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    <a href="<?= URL::toRoute('meter/report') ?>" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Download PDF</a>// on this button click the actionReport() is called

</p>
```

**GridView**

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'description',
        'meter_msn',
        //'meter_type',
        [
            'label' => 'Meter Type',
            'value' => function ($d) {
                if(is_object($d))
                    return $d->meter_type;
                return ' - ';
            },
            'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'meter_type', \app\models\Meters::getMeterTypeValues(), ['prompt' => "Meter Type", 'class' => 'form-control']),

        ],
        //'sub_div',
        [
            'label' => 'Sub Division Name',
            'value' => function ($d) {
                if(is_object($d->subdiv))
                return $d->subdiv->name;
             return ' - ';
            },
            'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'sub_div', \common\models\SurveyHescoSubdivision::toArrayList(), ['prompt' => "Sub-Div", 'class' => 'form-control']),

        ],


        //'meter_status',
        [
            'label' => 'Meter Status',
            'value' => function ($d) {
                    return $d->meter_status;
            },
            'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'meter_status', \app\models\Meters::getMeterStatus(), ['prompt' => "Meter Status", 'class' => 'form-control']),

        ],
        //'status',
        [
            'label'=>'Status',
            'value'=>function($a){
                    return $a->getStatusvalue();
            }
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Issued User',
            'value' => function ($d) {
                if(is_object($d->user))
                    //return $d->user->name;
                    return $d->issued_user == '' ? '' : $d->user->username;
                return ' - ';
               // return $d->user->name;

            },
            'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'issued_user', \app\models\User::toArrayList(), ['prompt' => "Users", 'class' => 'form-control']),

        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Created By',
            'value' => function ($data) {
                if (is_object($data))
                    return $data->created->name;
                return ' - ';
            },

        ],
        'created_at:date',
        'historic',
        'comments',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],

    ],
]); ?>
```

On button click, an action controller is called and inside it, I am trying to access the `value` of the select `sub_div`.

```
function actionReport()
{

   $sub_div = isset($_REQUEST['MetersSearch[sub_div]'])?$_REQUEST['MetersSearch[sub_div]']:'';
   print_r($sub_div);
   die();

}
```

But it's giving me empty view with no value shown.

How can I access it? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: dropdown should be inside form

Comment: It is inside the form

Comment: Try to access like this : $_REQUEST['MetersSearch']['sub_div']

Comment: tried with both `$_REQUEST['MetersSearch']['sub_div'];` it gives me `Undefined index: MetersSearch` and with `isset($_REQUEST['MetersSearch']['sub_div'] )?$_REQUEST['MetersSearch']['sub_div'] :'';` it gives me empty view

Comment: have you check what you get in request using var_dump($_REQUEST)

Comment: yes it's `array(0) { }`

Comment: Can u provide full code what you have did

Comment: seems that you are not sending  data  .. then code you provided  is not enough

Comment: @scaisEdge What you want me to update?

Comment: as request by @RajeshYadav  show the full code of your view

Comment: @scaisEdge I have updated the question kindly check

Comment: @RajeshYadav Check the update 1

Comment: ohk, you want your filter value to in generate pdf

Comment: @RajeshYadav yes, and there will be more than one filter values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need filter value in Report controller.For that you need to pass values using **Querystring**.

you can get filter value in view index page as below.

```
$sub_div = isset($_REQUEST['MetersSearch']['sub_div'])?$_REQUEST['MetersSearch']['sub_div']:'';
```

Now to can pass this values to controller.

```
<a href="<?= URL::toRoute('meter/report').'?sub_div='.$sub_div ?>" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Download PDF</a>
```

In **report** controller you will get **sub_div**

```
function actionReport()
{
   $sub_div = $_REQUEST['sub_div'];
   print_r($sub_div);
   die();
}
```

Comment: `<a href="<?= URL::toRoute('meter/report').'?sub_div='.$sub_div ?>" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Download PDF</a>` gives me `Undefined variable: sub_div`

Comment: I was doing in wrong way. Your method works for me :)